# How to create matrix from list in r

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list consist of adjacency list the data look like this

```
    Test User_ID hardest
1   77      A       5
2   77      B       4
3   77      C       4
4   78      A       4
5   78      B       5
6   78      C       4
7   79      A       5
8   79      B       4  ...
```

I want to make a matrix like column consist of test number and row is consist of User ID
and cell in the matrix is hardest, It looks like below

```
   77   78   79
A   5    4    5 
B   4    5    4
C   4    4        ....
```

how can I convert this list to matrix?

Comment: In addition to good answer below, a base R solution`reshape(df, idvar = "User_ID", timevar = "Test" , direction = "wide")`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
 dcast(df, User_ID~Test, value.var='hardest')
 #   User_ID 77 78 79
 #1       A  5  4  5
 #2       B  4  5  4
 #3       C  4  4 NA
```

If it is a matrix you want

```
 acast(df, User_ID~Test, value.var='hardest')
 #   77 78 79
 #A  5  4  5
 #B  4  5  4
 #C  4  4 NA
```

Or  `tidyr`

```
 library(tidyr)
 spread(df, Test, hardest)
 #    User_ID 77 78 79
 #1       A  5  4  5
 #2       B  4  5  4
 #3       C  4  4 NA
```

Or using `xtabs`

```
x1 <- xtabs(hardest~User_ID+Test, df)
attr(x1, "call") <- NULL
attr(x1, "class") <- NULL
dimnames(x1) <- unname(dimnames(x1))
x1
#  77 78 79
#A  5  4  5
#B  4  5  4
#C  4  4  0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Test = c(77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L
), User_ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B"), hardest = c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), .Names = c("Test", "User_ID", "hardest"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: I don't think you need to assign a matrix class to a table object created by `xtabs`. Table-objects inherit from matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, 1st solution is fits in my data. Although my first question may make you annoying example, you save me time a lot thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

From base package, you can try

```
tapply(df$hardest,df[,c("User_ID","Test")],sum)
```